# Customizing django settings file original template

Tags: django, templates, path, settings, customizing

Everybody have to change the `settings.py` file every time you start a new django project.
I think this routine applies for everyone run the `manage.py startproject myproject` command, when you have to type the same admin name, timezone, templates_dir ... every freaking time.

So I thought if there is way to make this routine modifications came preset for you from the beginning?

I know there is a template file that `startproject` command use to prepare the settings file, I just can't find it anywhere.
can anybody here give me the path of that file?

knowingly I'm using ubuntu and django 1.3.

Comment: Customizing the `startproject` template was one of the improvements in the 1.4 release: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/releases/1.4/#custom-project-and-app-templates Something to look forward to when you upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you locate the Django installation (I'd search for it in `/usr/share/pyshared/django`, at least that is the location on Debian; on Gentoo it is `/usr/lib/python<version>/site-packages/django`), the location inside the package is `conf/project_template`.

Anyway, I wouldn't generally recommend modifying the contents of a package installed by the package manager, instead consider using a virtualenv with its local customized Django installation.

Comment: Thank, by the way I found some git repo, have too many customization options, and I think the new feature added to django 1.4 base on it.
check this out [link](https://github.com/lincolnloop/django-startproject)

Answer (score 0):

I just keep a customized settings.py in my home directory and copy it to the project directory after running `startproject`. Simple and effective.